# How can I access item from nested ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access scope of nested ng-repeat. Specifically clicked item. How can I achieve this?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="get(item)">
    <div ng-repeat="book in books" ng-click="get(book)">
        {{book.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and controller

```
$scope.get = function(item){
       console.log(item);
};
```

I am able to get only item scope, how can I get scope of book? If I apply both functions, it triggers both functions, I only want clicked item.

## Edit

Example

```
$scope.json = {
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Tom",
        "pub": "Cruise",
        "photo": ".jpg",
        "topics": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "pages": "31"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "pages": "300"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Maria",
        "pub": "Sharapova",
        "photo": ".jpeg",
        "topics": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "pages": "321"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "pages": "500"
          }
          ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It can be more nested.

```
<div ng-repeat="book in json.data.books" ng-click="get(book)">
    <div><bold>{{book.name}}</bold></div>
    <div ng-repeat="topic in book" ng-click="get(topic)">
        {{topic.pages}}
    </div>
</div>
```

It gives me result like this,

```
Tom
31
300

Maria
321
500
```

now if I click on 31, I need topics object only using

```
 function get(topic){
      console.log(topic);
   }

console:
    {
      "id": "1",
      "pages": "31"
    }
```

and if I click on Tom, I need the book scope

```
 function get(book){
          console.log(book);
     }
```

result should be like this,

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Tom",
        "pub": "Cruise",
        "photo": ".jpg",
        "topics": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "pages": "31"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "pages": "300"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: On what basis you want to get `book` scope ?

Comment: Not very clear what you want to achieve here. Are these lists independant?

Comment: @JeetPatel have you tried `ng-click="get(book,item)"` ?

Comment: @MikeRoss ng-click="get(book,item)" gives me 'undefined', I have also tried   $scope.dealWithItem = function () {
  console.log(this);
 }

Comment: @BillP I only want to get clicked item scope from above ng-repeat.

Comment: @JeetPatel please add your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `ng-click` to inner element:

```
<div ng-repeat="book in json.data.books">
    <div ng-click="get(book)"><b>{{book.name}}</b></div>
    <div ng-repeat="topic in book.topics">
        <div ng-click="get(topic)">{{topic.pages}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working demo: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s034ceza/19/)

Comment: oh I was close., I was doing <div ng-repeat="book in json.data.books" ng-click="get(book);">, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
function get(topic, refItem){
    console.log(topic);
    if (refItem) {
        console.log(refItem); 
        //or console.log(JSON.stringify(refItem);
    }
}

<div ng-repeat="book in json.data.books" ng-click="get(book)">
    <div><bold>{{book.name}}</bold></div>
    <div ng-repeat="topic in book" ng-click="get(topic, book)">
        {{topic.pages}}
    </div>
</div>
```

or you can create 2 or more function like this:

```
function getBook(book){
    console.log(book);
}

function getTopic(topic, book){
    console.log(topic);
    console.log(book);
}

<div ng-repeat="book in json.data.books" ng-click="getBook(book)">
    <div><bold>{{book.name}}</bold></div>
    <div ng-repeat="topic in book" ng-click="getTopic(topic, book)">
        {{topic.pages}}
    </div>
</div>
```